# Does a big market exist for OSX app store development?

Tags: macos, mac, mac-appstore, development

I'm a developer who has delved a little into Android and iOS development. Both huge markets in terms of downloads, exposure, and opportunity to make a little bit of money.

However, I've started playing with OSX development and am loving it. I would like to develop for it more frequently, however, it doesn't seem like there's a huge market. The apps found on the Mac store usually have a very low number of ratings, very few comments, and Apple doesn't list the number of downloads. It's hard for me to get a good idea of the market.

With that being said, do you believe there's a market? If you're a developer yourself, has your OSX development experience proven that there is a market?

I would like to understand the market potential before I invest time, effort, and buy the Mac developer license.

Thanks.